# How to estimate $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!} {n \choose k}$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, estimation

I want to estimate this summation

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!} {n \choose k}$$

It seems to be about $\sqrt{n}$

how can i prove that?

---

It rises from the problem of calculating the expectation value of longest increasing subsequence of a given sequence. if some one has another idea for solving the original problem i will be pleased for sharing.

Thanks...

Comment: Not fleshed-out enough to be a proper answer, but: your sum is also $\sum_k\frac1{k!}{n\choose n-k}$; as such, it looks as though each individual term can be written as a sort of convolution and so you may be able to construct an explicit generating function as a product of two other series?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I tried it, it caused to estimate the coefficients of $(x+1)^n \times e^x$ which is not easy

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1948273/estimation-for-a-combinatorial-expression#comment3999726_1948273 , and I believe the asymptotic for such a sum is $e^{C\sqrt{n}}+\ldots$ i.e. it grows faster than any polynomial, but slower than any exponential.

Comment: The integral $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{(z+1)^n e^z}{z^{n+1}}\,dz $$ can be approximated through the saddle point method, see Flajolet - Analytic Combinatorics.

Comment: And the strictly related series $$\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{n^k}{k!^2}$$ is the Bessel function $I_0(2\sqrt{n})$, with known asymptotics (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sum is equal to $L_n(-1)-1$, where $L_n$ is a [Laguerre Polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials) (see specifically the closed form given in the link).

The same page also provides asymptotics (with $\alpha=0$ for generalized Laguerre):

$$L_n(-x)\approx \frac{(n+1)^{-1/4}}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{e^{-x/2}}{x^{1/4}}e^{2\sqrt{x(n+1)}}\left(1+O(1/\sqrt{n+1})\right),$$

so just plug in $x=1$. It looks like the growth rate will be something like:

$$\frac{e^{\sqrt{n}}}{n^{1/4}}.$$